# Child doesn't expand when parent has min-height set

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make min-height work. The main problem is, my child doesn't get height of parent, thus doesn't set its own height. How can i fix this?

```css
#middle_Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 85vh;
  max-height: 500%;
  height: auto;
}

#main {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle_Wrapper">
  <main id="main">
     test
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: remove height:auto from parent div.

Comment: You have to set some `height` explicitly on `#middle_Wrapper`.

Comment: That doesn't do the trick, i tried it already.

But if i set the height, and add more text into HTML, it won't expand, will it?

Answer (score 4):

Change `height : auto` to `height : 0`

```css
#middle_Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-height: 500%;
  height: 0; /* change this line */
}

#main {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle_Wrapper">
  <main id="main">
     test
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add css, you are using `%` so change it into `vh`.

```
#main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
#middle_Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-height: 500%;
  height: auto;
}

#main {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle_Wrapper">
  <main id="main">
     test
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhh, the main problem is, i forgot to add i wan't the div to expand as more and more HTML text is added, that applies to parent.